# jQuery: Change specific text color

Tags: jquery

I can't seem to figure this out.  I have the code below in my web page, how do I change the "Click here" to blue or some color using jQuery?

```
<td width="30%" valign="top" align="left" 
class="td-label-276-7365 td-label-276 labeltext" 
id="td-label-field-7365">Flavors [Click here] :
</td>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to change the color of "Click here" and you absolutely must use JS, then you can do:

```
var text = $('td').text();
text = text.replace(/\[Click\shere\]/g, '[<font color="blue">Click here</font>]');
$('td').html(text);
```

But it is more advisable to just do it directly with html and css, like:

```
<td width="30%" ...>Flavors [<span class="blue">Click here</span>] :</td>
```

and in your CSS:

```
span.blue {
   color: blue;
}
```

**Demo:** Both approaches can be seen **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/XPSPU/)**

Comment: Hi Techfoobar and thank you - the app is an autogen php app for various clients so I can't stick this html in like this, so I wanted to added some jquery to specific account changes.

Comment: Ahh, ok. In that case, the first option should suit your need.

Comment: question:  I got a very weird output when i added this, but I see this does a replace, but shouldn't there be a find or search because this is a long form with several labels and fields.  What I think it is doing is finding the text in every <td>

Comment: Yes, the 'td' selector in my answer above is just a placeholder. You will need to replace that with your TD's class or id. For example: `$('td#td-label-field-7365')`

Answer (score 1):

use [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
 $('#td-label-field-7365').css('color','blue');
```

**updated**

if you need to change color just in  [Click here], thn ad span around it and use `css()`

**html**

```
<td width="30%" valign="top" align="left" 
class="td-label-276-7365 td-label-276 labeltext" 
id="td-label-field-7365">Flavors <span>[Click here]</span>
</td>
```

**jquery**

```
$('#td-label-field-7365 span').css('color','blue');
```

Comment: but I need to change some specific text, not all the text within the #td.

Comment: Hi bipen - because this app is an autogen php app for various clients, I can't stick html/css in like this, but I see your principle.  Thank you.

Comment: sure.. welcome... if cannot modify the HTML then.. replace is the best way... and with replace, i think @techfoobar has done it... anyways.. cheers ..:)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#td-label-field-7365').css('color', 'blue');
```

Comment: You missed the #. This will look for any tags called `td-label-field-7365` like it would look for div's if you put `'div'`

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.labeltext').css('color','blue');
```