# Change color of a portion of text using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to change the color of a portion of the text "( SOLD )" to red in the following example text like :

```
<h1 class="myClass">( SOLD ) BMW X5 Diesel...</h1>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Question is already answered enough times... [jQuery: Change specific text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386381/jquery-change-specific-text-color)

Answer (score -2):

```
<h1 class="othercolor MyClass">( SOLD )</h1><h1 class="MyClass"> BMW X5 Diesel...</h1>
```

and then in your .css file you set up the color like this:

```
.othercolor {
  color: red; !important
}
```

Basically, you have MyClass where I am assuming that you set your style, but then with othercolor you set the new color, and then close it, so the rest would be in regular h1 as you have set.

There are other ways of doing it with jquery

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This is a blog post and I would like to change the color only for posts where the title contain ( SOLD ). Is there a way to do it with jQuery ? Thanks

Comment: $(".myClass").html(function () {
    return $(this).html().replace("( SOLD )", "<span class='myColor'>( SOLD )</span>");
}); is working. Thanks